# Hive query returns null while executing against Cassandra columnfamily

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra, hql, hive

I've mapped the Hive table columns with corresponding Cassandra columns. But while executing the Hive query it is returning the null value for all the columns excluding row key.

When applying HQL count on some Hive columns result is zero. At the same time, for row key count it is returning the exact count in this query (it is returned as four). What can be the problem? Why it is returning null values for all the columns?

```
hive> select * from Users;       
OK
21  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
22  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
20  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
25  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: cassandra column family creation String qry="create columnfamily Users(key varchar primary key,name varchar,password varchar,message varchar,phone bigint)";

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the problem, you need to use the GenericUDF class to write a user-defined
function, called nvl()

i can answer it more efficiently if you post structure of your table
sorry if i am wrong
Thankyou

Comment: create external table Users(key string, name string,password string,message string,phone bigint)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("cassandra.columns.mapping" = ":key,:column,:value",
  "cassandra.ks.name" = "HiveTesting",
  "cassandra.ks.repfactor" = "1",
  "cassandra.ks.strategy" = "org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy",
  "cassandra.cf.name" = "Users" ,
  "cassandra.host" = "127.0.0.1" ,
  "cassandra.port" = "9160",
  "cassandra.partitioner" = "org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner");